# How to convert the following query over to linq?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm new to nhibernate 3.0:

I got 3 objects (not code just description)

class a{
prop b;
}

class b{
prop c
}

class c{
long id
}

I wrote the following query over code

```
session.QueryOver<a>().
JoinQueryOver<b>(a1 => a1.b, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).
JoinQueryOver<c>(b1 => b1.c, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).
Where(c1=>c1.id == someNumber);
```

and i get exactly the query I expected to get!

Is it possible to write it in linq ? how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left joins are not yet supported in the LINQ provider.